# iPhone: UITextfield validation

Tags: iphone, ios

I checked the existing examples here in S.O, for my case which one do you think is better,

There are many textfields in one view and I want to validate them just when the user is editing that particular textfield, cause otherwise I have to validate them together when user press next on the screen than I have show all validation messages which I dont want to bother with. I want to validate the textfield in 2 different ways, if its a number input I want to validate it in a defined range e.g if number between between 5 and 1000 or if its a text then if the lenght of the text is in a defined range e.g between 2 and 10 characters. And the user must be able to enter any input out of range.

Which is better;

Using textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange

or something like this:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(validateField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And either the case how can I check on runtime that the number entered is in range and dont allow user to enter bigger or smaller numbers

Answer (score 0):

Good one.

The answer for your question is
1) Set the tag values to all the textfields.
2) Use `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin` and trigger a method to validate the textfield before the currentone.

```
 [textfield1 setTag:1];
   [textfield2 setTag:2];// make sure to set tag values incrementally
   [textfield2 addTarget:self @selector(validate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
-(void) validate:(id) sender
{
    // 10 is the number of textfields, change it accordingly.

    if(sender.tag!=1 && sender.tag!=10)
    {

          //validate textfield with tag sender.tag-1
    }
    else
    {
         //handle first and last textfield here
    }
}
```

Try this, probably this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both of your approaches will be just fine! Using the `delegate` of the `UITextField` to call `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange` and perform the validation there is an equally good approach as using *Target & Action*. In both situations, you define a handler that receives the calling `UITextField` as an argument (one implementation of this is what @Anil Kumar suggested in his answer to tag the text fields. but this is actually not even required, you can just call `isEqual:` on the text fields directly to check for equality).

Personally, I tend to use delegation for these kinds of tasks though.

**Update:** If you want to go really fancy on this problem, you'll use [Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa). The [April Tech Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWV7xyN5CR8) of the Ray Wenderlich Gang had a great session on it and also discusses the issue of from validation, so it'll just match your case! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TextFieldValidator](https://github.com/anukooll/TextFieldValidator) developed in swift